# How to execute an output string without bash's command substitution?

Tags: bash, apt, pipe, xargs, process-substitution

How to execute an output string without bash's command substitution?

For example, if I type in terminal `tshark`, and the program isn't installed yet, I will recieve an error message like:

```
_some text_
sudo apt-get install tshark
```

Now I want to execute this last line without copy&paste or transcription.

If I try

```
$ tshark 2> >(tail -1)
sudo apt-get install tshark
```

I will get this last line I want to execute.

And if I want to execute this string, of course bash's command substitution  works and install everything properly:

```
$ $(tshark 2> >(tail -1))
```

But if I don't use bash's command substitution, and pipe this to xargs like

```
$ tshark 2> >(tail -1) | xargs
sudo apt-get install tshark
```

I am wondering why piping to xargs seems to have no effect.

But if I try

```
$ tshark 2> >(tail -1) | xargs xargs
```

`sudo` prompt's me correct for password, and than `apt-get` abbort's after Y/N for installing or not.

The same result occurs if I pipe to `bash`.

Any response or hint is welcome.

Comment: `xagrs` treats `stdin` as a list of *arguments*: if you don't give a command on the RHS it's equivalent to `xargs echo`. AFAIK it has no way to know that the first argument should be treated  specially (i.e. as the command). Something like `xargs -I{} bash -c '{}'` *might* work.

Comment: Ok, is there a way for executing the output with `xargs`? I have already tried `xargs -I{} bash -c '{}'`. This also abborts after Y/N:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Answer

You cannot reuse the output of a command that was not explicitly captured (pipes, etc.) unless you re-execute the command and capture the output yourself.

Bash does not store command *output* in any variables, unlike how it does store command exit codes and command history. Your *terminal* has the output and bash does not bother keeping a copy for itself as well.

So if you want to avoid command substitution all together, I am going to conclude you can't get there from here.

### Options

If the real question is "How can I *easily* grab the output that I see on the line above in the terminal and slap it into the command prompt as a command without a lot of typing?" you can tackle this a couple of ways.

1. Use `readline` shortcuts to make editing a command more painless.

For example, your response to @choroba's fine suggestion elsewhere is that editing the last command is too much typing. The readline shortcuts <kbd>CTRL-a</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL-e</kbd> can make editing the last command (reached with <kbd>CTRL-p</kbd> instead of the <kbd>UP</kbd> waaaay over to the right) much faster.

2. Use a terminal multiplexer such as `screen` or `tmux`. I prefer `tumx`. Copying and pasting is pretty painless with a simple <kbd>CTRL-a</kbd> <kbd>CTRL-[</kbd> to jump into copy mode and a few more VI keys and you have just copied the line you want right into the next prompt (with `tmux` setup with a <kbd>CTRL-a</kbd> leader key.

Hope this offers some other perspectives.

Comment: Yes thank you, I was looking for an faster way with less typing. The fastest way seems to be a combination with `up` and `ctrl-a`.

Answer (score 1):

`xargs` executes the command you specify on the arguments read from standard input. If no command was specified, it uses `echo`.

With `xargs xargs`, the first xargs reads the commands and runs

```
xargs sudo apt-get install tshark
```

but there's no more stdin, so no more arguments are added. But as there's no stdin, there are also no replies to interactive questions - they are reading from stdin, which is connected to the pipe, now exhausted. You can try running apt-get with `--yes`. (Prompting for password works as passwords are **not** read from stdin for security reasons).

Comment: Thank you for the xargs's hints. But mostly I was asking "How to execute an output string without bash's command substitution?" Do you have any hints for that?

Comment: Why do you need to avoid command substitution?

Comment: I don't need to avoid command substitution. But it is more convenient to type after an output instead of using the arrow-keys for getting the last output and than going to the end of line to type a `)` and than go to the beginning of the line to type `$(`.